# How to retrieve specific user's posts on a page using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve the posts on a page's wall but only of a particular user. I am unable to query the graph api with filter. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such filtering available. If you need this, you will have to do the filtering on your end.

You will either have to go through the page's feed and check the `from` field of the posts for the user id, or through the user's posts (requires that you get `user_posts` permission from the user first) checking the `to` field for the page id.

Comment: If i do this, then I have to loop through the data to filter it according to my needs which is not an optimized way. If u have any suggestions on how I can filter data on my end besides iterating through the data.